# C# Navigate to Anchors in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

We have a web browser in our Winforms app to nicely display history of a selected item rendered by xslt.

The xslt is writing out <a> tags in the outputted html to allow the webBrowser control to navigate to the selected history entry.

As we are not 'navigating' to the html in the strict web sense, rather setting the html by the DocumentText, I can't 'navigate' to desired anchors with a #AnchorName, as the webBrowser's Url is null (edit: actually on completion it is about:blank).

How can I dynamically navigate to Anchor tags in the html of the Web Browser control in this case?

**EDIT:**

Thanks sdolphion for the tip, this is the eventual code I used

```
void _history_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _completed = true;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_requestedAnchor))
        {
            JumpToRequestedAnchor();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void JumpToRequestedAnchor()
    {
        HtmlElementCollection elements = _history.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
        foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("Name") == _requestedAnchor)
            {
                element.ScrollIntoView(true);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am sure someone has a better way of doing this but here is what I used to accomplish this task.

```
HtmlElementCollection elements = this.webBrowser.Document.Body.All;
foreach(HtmlElement element in elements){
   string nameAttribute = element.GetAttribute("Name");
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameAttribute) && nameAttribute == section){
      element.ScrollIntoView(true);
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just found a reference to this online and am testing it now. Will mark as answer when I confirm it.

Comment: Though I am using Document.GetElementByName rather than the loop

Comment: Thank you for posting back your update I changed mine to more closely match yours.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is old and has a great answer, but this hasn't been suggested yet, so it might be useful for others that come here looking for an answer.

Another way to do it is use the element id in the HTML.

`<p id="section1">This is a test section</p>`

Then you can use

```
HtmlElement sectionAnchor = webBrowserPreview.Document.GetElementById("section1");
if (sectionAnchor != null)
{
    sectionAnchor.ScrollIntoView(true);
}
```

where webBrowserPreview is your WebBrowser control.

Alternatively, `sectionAnchor.ScrollIntoView(false)` will only bring the element on screen instead of aligning it with the top of the page

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. Where does `webBrowserPreview` get defined?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that and nobody noticed before now. It's a WebBrowser control in your form. I've added that clarification to my answer.